# VB6 DLL takes callback as Integer, VB.NET requires delegate reference type

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com+, g15

I have an issue with a third-party COM+ DLL meant to be used from VB6, where it has a function to set a Callback for a hardware event.  However, I'm using VB.NET, and AddressOf now returns a reference type instead of an integral type, which means that the setCallback function on the COM+ DLL apparently can't be used.

Is there a way around this problem (I don't have VB6 available to develop some sort of wrapper with), or will I have to find a different 3rd-party DLL in order to get this to work?  For reference, I'm trying to access the LCD on a Logitech G15(v2) keyboard.

For Reference, here is the setCallback function and the callback's prototype itself:

```
Public Sub setCallback(funcAddr As Integer)
Public Sub LCDbuttonPress(ByVal butStates As Integer)
```

Comment: Knowing the prototype for the callback would be helpful here.

Comment: Public Sub setCallback(funcAddr As Integer)

Public Sub LCDbuttonPress(ByVal butStates As Integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you declare your setCallback function like this:

```
Public Sub setCallback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]funcAddr as function)
```

I'm not a VB guy, so I don't know the exact syntax. But the basic idea here is that in VB.Net you declare the prototype as taking a delegate, even a delegate of the correct type.  But then you use the MarshalAs attribute to tell the marshalling code to treat it as a function pointer (actually a Integer) on the other side.  I do this in C# to pass callbacks to C++ code and it works just fine.

For instance this in C#

```
public delegate int MyProgress(double dPercentComplete);
...
int WaitWithProgress([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]MyProgress pfn);
```

Shows up on the C++ side of the house as this

```
HRESULT __stdcall WaitWithProgress (long pfn, int * pRetVal);
```

Note the comments.  The actual solution to this problem turned out to be `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`  And be careful to read the docs on this.  If you use this method, it becomes your responsibility to make sure that the delegate isn't garbage collected before you `setCallback(NULL)`

Comment: The problem here is that setCallback is a function in the DLL, so I cannot change it or the function definition at all.

Comment: You aren't changing the the callback, you are just changing the prototype *as VB.NET sees it*.  Then using MarshalAs to contol how it converts what VB.NET sees to what VB6 sees.

Comment: John: As far as I can tell, VS2008 is taking the prototype for setCallback *from* the DLL, so what I'm saying is that as far as I understand I can't redeclare the callback with the MarshalAs parameter in place there.  If I'm wrong, then I apologize for being difficult.

Comment: I suspect that there is some way to get it to use an alternate prototype.  But I'm no VB guy, so I have no idea how to go about it.
How about `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the `Marshal.GetFunctionPointer...` note, that fixed it perfectly!